# Access update statement not working in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I'm going crazy trying to find out the reason why the below code won't update my database. I appreciate any help.
  The connection string is correct and I'm able to execute similar commands, only this one is not working for some reason. Basically what I want is to replace occurrences of the value "1" with "123" in a column that I pass to the method.

```
        public void removeExpired2(string column, string user)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=d:\DB.accdb";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Reservations] SET [" + column + "] = @Column WHERE [" + column + "] = @ID");
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column", "123");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "1");
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Button1, this.GetType(), "AlertMsg", "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');</script>", false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But you are replacing `123` with `1`

Comment: I made this mistake while changing the values here to make it easier to explain, but in my code the issue still stands. Is there anything wrong with the statement itself, other than the opposite values?

Comment: Did you check return value of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Answer (score 2):

> Basically what I want is to replace occurrences of the value "1" with "123"

Your query is doing just opposite.

Change this

```
"UPDATE [Reservations] SET [" + column + "] = @Column WHERE [" + column + "] = @ID"
```

to

```
"UPDATE [Reservations] SET [" + column + "] = @ID WHERE [" + column + "] = @Column"
```

---

OR

Do this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Column", "123");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", "1");
```

Comment: I made this mistake while changing the values here to make it easier to explain, but in my code the issue still stands. Is there anything wrong with the statement itself, other than the opposite values?

Answer (score 0):

I had the command executed with two other commands, so I tried to separate them and it seems to have fixed the issue.
  I moved one command into its own method and the remaining two are as they were before, and it's working now. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is ,the parameters must be added to the command object in the same order they appear in the SQL statement.

Comment: Thats not true...

Comment: Access doesn't use named parameters, but positional. So in this case the order is important

Comment: Exactly, this is what is have mentioned in my answer above. I have created a Regex that extracts the command parameters from the SQL statement and added them to the command object in a loop.